# Why my isPrime Function can't work?

Tags: haskell

I have my isPrime function in haskell like this:

```
isPrime = \x -> length (filter (\y -> x `mod` y == 0) [2..(x - 1)]) == 0
```

And it works fine.

But when I was about to optimize the function like this:

```
isPrime = \x -> length (filter (\y -> x `mod` y == 0) [2..(floor(sqrt x))]) == 0
```

Some error occur, why would that happen?

Well, the Error code is:

```
Euler.hs:34:41:
    No instance for (Integral a0) arising from a use of ‘mod’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      y :: a0 (bound at Euler.hs:34:34)
      x :: a0 (bound at Euler.hs:34:12)
      isPrime :: a0 -> Bool (bound at Euler.hs:34:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Integral Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Integral Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Integral GHC.Types.Word -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
    In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘x `mod` y’
    In the expression: x `mod` y == 0
    In the first argument of ‘filter’, namely ‘(\ y -> x `mod` y == 0)

Euler.hs:34:49:
    No instance for (Eq a0) arising from a use of ‘==’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      y :: a0 (bound at Euler.hs:34:34)
      x :: a0 (bound at Euler.hs:34:12)
      isPrime :: a0 -> Bool (bound at Euler.hs:34:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Eq a => Eq (GHC.Real.Ratio a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Eq () -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
      instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (a, b) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
      ...plus 23 others
    In the expression: x `mod` y == 0
    In the first argument of ‘filter’, namely ‘(\ y -> x `mod` y == 0)
    In the first argument of ‘length’, namely
      ‘(filter (\ y -> x `mod` y == 0) [2 .. (floor (sqrt x))])’

Euler.hs:34:52:
    No instance for (Num a0) arising from the literal ‘0’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      y :: a0 (bound at Euler.hs:34:34)
      x :: a0 (bound at Euler.hs:34:12)
      isPrime :: a0 -> Bool (bound at Euler.hs:34:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      ...plus three others
    In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘0’
    In the expression: x `mod` y == 0
    In the first argument of ‘filter’, namely ‘(\ y -> x `mod` y == 0)

Euler.hs:34:55:
    No instance for (Enum a0)
      arising from the arithmetic sequence ‘2 .. (floor (sqrt x))’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      x :: a0 (bound at Euler.hs:34:12)
      isPrime :: a0 -> Bool (bound at Euler.hs:34:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Enum Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Enum Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Integral a => Enum (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      ...plus 7 others
    In the second argument of ‘filter’, namely
      ‘[2 .. (floor (sqrt x))]’
    In the first argument of ‘length’, namely
      ‘(filter (\ y -> x `mod` y == 0) [2 .. (floor (sqrt x))])’
    In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely
      ‘length (filter (\ y -> x `mod` y == 0) [2 .. (floor (sqrt x))])’

Euler.hs:34:60:
    No instance for (RealFrac a0) arising from a use of ‘floor’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      x :: a0 (bound at Euler.hs:34:12)
      isPrime :: a0 -> Bool (bound at Euler.hs:34:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance RealFrac Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance RealFrac Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Integral a => RealFrac (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
    In the expression: (floor (sqrt x))
    In the second argument of ‘filter’, namely
      ‘[2 .. (floor (sqrt x))]’
    In the first argument of ‘length’, namely
      ‘(filter (\ y -> x `mod` y == 0) [2 .. (floor (sqrt x))])’

Euler.hs:34:66:
    No instance for (Floating a0) arising from a use of ‘sqrt’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      x :: a0 (bound at Euler.hs:34:12)
      isPrime :: a0 -> Bool (bound at Euler.hs:34:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Floating Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Floating Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
    In the first argument of ‘floor’, namely ‘(sqrt x)’
    In the expression: (floor (sqrt x))
    In the second argument of ‘filter’, namely
      ‘[2 .. (floor (sqrt x))]’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

It seems that there are some problems with the mod function and floor function?

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: A simple test shows these functions are giving similar results, call the functions `isPrime` and `isPrime'`: `take 1 $ filter (\x -> isPrime x && not (isPrime' x)) [1..100000]` returns `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second function get's a strange type inferred without signatures:

```
isPrime :: (RealFrac a, Integral a, Floating a) => a -> Bool
```

I'm not sure that any type is an instance of all those classes(Int and Double are definitely not). So your function is fine you just can't provide a value that it's operating on.

Comment: Oh, thanks for you answer, I think that there is something wrong with my type. Since sqrt is called, x is treated as a floating point value. but a mod function is also called, and thus the problem occurs.

Comment: I changed my code like this:    isPrime = \x -> length (filter (\y -> (floor x) `mod` y == 0) [2..(floor(sqrt x))]) == 0

Comment: @Noah That's probably not what you want, you want the argument to be of an integral type.  Try to define a square root function that works on integral values, and then use that.